# What facts are used implicitly to make the following deductions?

Tags: real-analysis

What facts are used implicitly to make the following deductions?

$\frac{x+2}{y} < 4x+1$

$\Rightarrow \frac{y}{x+2} > \frac{1}{4x+1}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{y^2}{(x+2)^2} > \frac{1}{(4x+1)^2} > \frac{1}{4x+1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first step, it requires $$(x+2) \neq 0$$ $$(4x+1) \neq 0$$ 
In the second step, it requires $${1 \over {4x+1}} > 1$$

It implies that $${1 \over {4x+1}} >0$$ $${y \over {x+2}} >0$$

Answer (score 0):

First that $\frac{x+2}y$ and $4x+1$ have the same sign, second that they're all positive and $4x+1<1$.

Comment: and third: 4x+1<1

Comment: @Mitkel: Yes, sorry, I saw as a conclusion (it's late…).. I'll add it. Thank you for pointing it.